# Homotopy between the identity and exponential of a near-idempotent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $I$ a proper ideal of $A$.

Let $h$ be an idempotent in $A/I$, and let $\tilde{h}$ be a lift of $h$ to $A$. Then a direct calculation shows that
$$e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}}\in I^+,$$
where we consider the unitization $I^+$ as a subalgebra of $A$ in the natural way. This can be verified using the series for the exponential function.

In the case that $\tilde{h}$ is itself an idempotent in $A$, we would have
$$e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}}=1_{I^+}$$
on the dot.

**Question:** Is there a constant $\delta>0$ (independent of $A$ and $I$) such that if the lift $\tilde{h}$ satisfies $\|\tilde{h}^2-\tilde{h}\|<\delta$, we have
$$e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}}\sim_h 1_{I^+},$$
where $\sim_h$ means homotopic through a path of invertibles in $I^+$?

*Remark:* I guess it suffices to show the existence of a $\delta$ such that starting from any "$\delta$-close idempotent" lift, one can produce an idempotent lift.

Comment: If $h$ is a **self-adjoint** element in a C*-algebra with $\|h^2-h\|$ small, the spectrum of $h$ is necessarily concentrated around 0 and 1, so you can use functional calculus to deform it to a projection.

Comment: I think even for idempotents one can do this using the holomorphic functional calculus, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.  A function which is constant 0 on a nbd of 0, and constant 1 on a nbd of 1 is holomorphic!

Comment: But wait a minute!  Even if the exponential lies in $I^+$, there is no reason for $\tilde h$ to be there.  In fact this is the whole fun of the index map in K-theory!